# Is it possible to limit user access to folders using HTACCESS?

Tags: apache, htaccess

Is it possible to limit user access using a HTACCESS file? I'm not quite sure how to edit folder permissions with the host i'm with so I figure using an HTACCESS file might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the host has support then you need this line.

```
deny from all
```

Related: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html

Comment: thats cool, is there a deny from some?

Comment: Yes, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny